# disable inherited transition (all) for only one css property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have in my CSS file the following code, which globally turns on transitions on all links for all CSS properties on anchor elements:

```
a{
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Later in CSS file, I would like to turn off transition on specific links (let's say with class `notrans`) but only for `background-position`.
Something like:

```
a.notrans{
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0;
    -moz-transition: background-position 0;
    -o-transition: background-position 0;
    -ms-transition: background-position 0;
    transition: background-position 0;
}
```

But this code does not work.

I must turn `background-position` transition and keep other transitions, so sprite - background image would not move on `a.notrans` ...

Comment: It seems like I found solution by myself:)

You just have to declare new property for transition, and old, inherited ones are gone.

So, i just used this>
    a.notrans{
    -webkit-transition:color .2s;
    -moz-transition:color .2s;
    -o-transition:color .2s;
    -ms-transition:color .2s;
    transition:color .2s;
    }
After this, only color transition is working!

Comment: Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to declare new property for transitions, and old inherited ones are gone.

So, i just used this>

```
a.notrans{
-webkit-transition:color .2s;
-moz-transition:color .2s;
-o-transition:color .2s;
-ms-transition:color .2s;
transition:color .2s;
}
```

After this, only color transition is working!

Maybe there is better solution ?